# How can I set a value after Select query in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I use simple select query:

```
SELECT
    transactiontype
FROM
    posfeed
LIMIT 100;
```

I result I have some rows with empty values.
I need set some default value in SELECT query result for some filed.

Something like:

```
if (transactiontype = '') {
  //SET SOME VALUE HERE
} else {
  //LEAVE
}
```

Comment: Are the values empty strings on nulls?

Comment: Then you can use `SELECT CASE WHEN transactiontype = '' THEN 'some_default_value' ELSE transactiontype END AS transactiontype ...`

Comment: Or (very very slightly shorter): `SELECT CASE transactiontype WHEN '' THEN 'some_default_value' ELSE transactiontype END AS transactiontype ...`

Comment: Thanks. This is what I need. And can I somehow use it in 'where' clause: WHERE transactiontype = 'some_default_value' ?

Comment: To use it in WHERE, you will need to run query more then once. SELECT CASE is the right answer to your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *and can I somehow use it in 'where' clause*

To use a column alias in the where clause you must wrap the select into a derived table:

```
select * 
from (
  SELECT CASE transactiontype 
           WHEN '' THEN 'some_default_value' 
           ELSE transactiontype 
         END AS transactiontype
  FROM the_table
) t 
where transactiontype = '...';
```

But I don't see the reason to do that, if you want to find those where the `some_default_value` is returned just run:

```
SELECT CASE transactiontype 
          WHEN '' THEN 'some_default_value' 
         ELSE transactiontype 
       END AS transaction_type
FROM the_table
where transactiontype =  '';
```

But that then doesn't really makes sense, because the above is equivalent to:

```
SELECT 'some_default_value' 
FROM the_table
where transactiontype =  '';
```

So I guess there is something you did not include in the question or your comments.